# Is there a way to specify a person just by hair color?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

You can say:

"Look, there is a blonde woman."

or

"Look, there is a gray woman."

If I am talking about hair color. But at the moment I say brown or black it is about skin color. And red just sounds strange. I have been thinking about this for a long time, and couldn't figure it out.
Of course 'brunette' is possible, but not with a word like 'woman' behind it.
So is there a good way of saying this, without suggesting skin color?

Comment: At the risk of digression, you missed out "scarlet woman" which describes neither hair nor skin. However, the priority of attribution (which attribute of someone is being described) is interesting. "There's a blue woman; there's a green woman; there's a Green."

Comment: The short answer to your question is "no", which is exactly why we have words like *blonde*, *brunette*, and *redhead*, which explicitly describe hair color, and can be applied with or without *woman*.

Comment: I don't understand.  "Blonde", "brunette", and "redhead" are commonly used to identify people (especially women) by hair color.  (Try hanging around a couple of guys in a bar some night -- one is apt to say to the other, "Hey, waddaya think about that blonde over in the corner?" or something of that nature.)  Do note, however, that using such terminology is apt to be considered rude/crude.  (And this has nothing at all to do with skin color.)

Comment: Interestingly, the terms for what seem to be the most common hair colors, *brown*, *black*, *grey* and *white*, do not stand alone as references to the person, while the rarer colors, *blonde, brunette* (to the extent it differs from common mousy brown), and *redhead* can stand alone as a noun-like term.

Comment: Blonde and black are both haircolors. If you just say 'that blonde (woman) in the corner' everyone knows you talk about her hair. If you say 'that black (woman) in the corner' nobody thinks you talk about a haircolor (but about a skincolor) though it is a haircolor.

Comment: Note that "blonde" works for a woman's hair color only if you say the final "e".  We should probably generalize that to using "rede" for female redhead, or "blacke" for female blackhead.

Comment: Noralie -- True.  That's English.  There is not a word for everything.  Instead, the language allows you to construct phrases to describe things.

Comment: @GregLee - Since when?  I've never heard the "e" pronounced in "blonde".  If the "e" sound is there it's spelled "blondie".

Comment: @HotLicks, "blonde" has a silent "e".

Comment: @GregLee - Then why did you say it only works if you say the final "e"???

Comment: @HotLicks, because it doesn't work.  You can't tell that it's a woman from the pronunciation.  That's obvious.

Comment: @GregLee - You very well can tell the sex of the individual from the pronunciation.  You just have to listen.  The two guys in the bar (unless it's a gay bar) will not say "Hey, waddaya think about that blonde over in the corner?" unless it's a woman.  If there is a guy with blonde hair they will say "See that guy with blonde hair in the corner?"

Comment: @GregLee But if you were to say: *Look at that gorgeous blond(e)?* You'd know we'd be talking about a female.

Answer (score 1):

> [**brunette**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/brunette)
> A girl or woman with brown hair.
>
> [**redhead**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Red+head)
> A person with red hair.

You cannot say a person is black for it to mean that he or she has black hair. A [Black](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/black?q=Black#black__15) is a noun which describes a person with brown to black skin, usually of African origin. I have black hair (well nowadays it's mostly dyed) and in Italy I can be called *mora* (a woman with black hair) and ironically/amusingly *bionda* (a woman with blonde hair).

In English you have the nouns: *blonde*, *brunette*, *redhead*, and *[ginger](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ginger)* which identify people via their hair color. Someone who has grey hair is often said to be *grey haired*. A grey (or gray) person has a different meaning, and means someone who is dull and nondescript. A *White* means any [Caucasian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Caucasian) person, and a "white woman" is a woman with light-coloured skin who belongs to a specific "racial" group. Therefore one must say *a white-haired woman* or *a woman with white hair*.

> - **Look at that woman's white hair!**
>   (this draws attention to the colour of her hair, perhaps it is strikingly white.)
> - **Look there's a white-haired woman**
>   (this sounds as if the speaker is surprised to see a woman with white hair. Maybe it is a rarity in that person's culture—more context is needed)

If the female is particularly young, and attractive you could describe her as being  a *[platinum blonde](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platinum%20blonde)*, think of Marilyn Monroe.

> **platinum blonde**
> a person whose hair is of a pale silvery-blonde color

Comment: Both answers are not exactly what I am looking for. I know it can be said that way, but I was wondering if it is possible to say it without specifying that you are talking about hair ( like when you say blonde) but by using it in front of woman for example.

Comment: I didn't see that the OP had already suggested "brunette" in the post. Too much haste on my part. The title however does  ask: *Is there a way to specify a person by hair color?*. A redhead means a person who has red hair. A brunette is a feminine noun, and means a **woman** or **girl** who has brown hair.

Comment: I didn't know how to ask the question in a better way, so that's why the title is maybe a bit misleading.

Comment: @Noralie: Blonde most definitely refers to hair.

Comment: So it is actually a strange thing that we do have words for red-haired, brown-haired, etc, but not for black-haired or gray-haired. Would there be an explanation etymology wise why this distinction exists?

Comment: @Noralie - There is little glamor in gray or white hair.  Hence it's a characteristic to be suppressed, not celebrated.  And black hair, in Caucasians, is quite rare.  (Likely some African languages have simple words for "black haired person", etc.)

Comment: @Hot, Well, we do have *silver fox* :)

Comment: I understand that *platinum blonde* (like *strawberry blonde* and *ash blonde*) actually refers to shade of hair colour, not to being young and glamorous. Marilyn Monroe, of course, was all three.

Comment: @Robusto, "blond/blonde" also refer to a wood finish.

Comment: @GregLee: One presumes that most people will not normally confuse people with wood treatments.